# Configuring nested Traffic Manager API Management in Azure

Tags: api, azure-api-management, azure-traffic-manager, apim

I have deployed an API Management service as internal vnet and created a dummy API. The Application Gateway is deployed which has the API Management service as the backend pool. 1 instance of AppGW and API management service are deployed in each reach region.

The traffic manager profile is deployed which has both the Application Gateways as the end points. The DNS entries are created for Traffic Manager profile and API Management gateway, developer portal, SCM, portal and management.

I am able to get the response from the API if I access the Traffic Manager.

I want to deploy a nested Traffic Manage profile with each API so that it can probe the health of the API's. What options do I need to choose in the child traffic Manager profile so that it can monitor the health of the API.

Answer (score 0):

> What options do I need to choose in the child traffic Manager profile
> so that it can monitor the health of the API.

If you want to monitor each API's health, I think you can select each API as the endpoints in the child traffic Manager profile and implement a custom monitoring page (path '/monitor.aspx') that includes additional checks or a custom path per endpoint.

Have a look at [Example 5: Per-endpoint monitoring settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-nested-profiles#example-5-per-endpoint-monitoring-settings)